# SQL Server Management Studio keyboard shortcut to highlighted Line Up and Down

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

What is the shortcut of the highlighted Line Up and Down. Like in the Visual studio.
I have SSMS 2014 and didnt find. Althought **lad2025** said  2017 have this option in Advance

[image]

Comment: are you talking about shift+up key

Comment: @TheGameiswar yes move to up and down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> for Move Selected Lines Up

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> for Move Selected Lines Down

---

SSMS -> Edit -> Advanced:

[image]

If it is not available I would recommend to upgrade [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) to newest version.

Comment: @SAL Strange, maybe because I have SSMS 17.1 Try to install newest release

Comment: Wha tis the name of this shortcut? i find in `tools`

Comment: @SAL Did you use left ALT?

Comment: @SAL Check if you have EDIT -> Advance this option. If not upgrade

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151784/discussion-between-sal-and-lad2025).